# SQL Server appears to round incorrectly

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which stores course results. A course may have more than one exam, each with its own weighting.

In this example, I have 2 exam marks for a student, which are then weighted to give the course mark. Both the mark and the weighting are stored in FLOAT columns.

Here's my code to extract the exam marks:

```
WITH RawData AS 
(
    SELECT 
        lngRelatedScoreID AS [ID],
        cc.strName AS Exam,
        cc.dblWeighting, 
        sci.dblModeratedComponentScorePercent AS Mark
    FROM 
        tblStudentComponentInformation sci 
    INNER JOIN 
        tblCourseComponents cc ON sci.lngExamID = cc.lngExamID
    WHERE 
        sci.lngRelatedScoreID IN (73652)
)
SELECT * FROM RawData
```

The results show as follows:

| ID | Exam | dblWeighting | Mark |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 73652 | Flight Dynamics and Control Exam | 0.75 | 0.905 |
| 73652 | Flight Dynamics and Control Coursework | 0.25 | 0.92 |

I now combine the two rows, multiplying the weighting by the mark:

```
WITH RawData AS 
(
    SELECT 
        lngRelatedScoreID AS ID,
        cc.strName AS Exam,
        cc.dblWeighting, 
        sci.dblModeratedComponentScorePercent AS Mark
    FROM 
        tblStudentComponentInformation sci 
    INNER JOIN 
        tblCourseComponents cc ON sci.lngExamID = cc.lngExamID
    WHERE 
        sci.lngRelatedScoreID IN (73652)
)
SELECT 
    [ID], 
    SUM(Mark * dblWeighting) AS TotalWeightedMark
FROM 
    RawData
GROUP BY 
    [ID]
```

which returns the following - as expected:

| ID | TotalWeightedMark |
| --- | --- |
| 73652 | 0.90875 |

However, I want the result to 4 decimal places, so when I multiply the mark by the rounding, and sum the result, I add in the `ROUND` function:

```
WITH RawData AS 
(
    SELECT 
        lngRelatedScoreID AS ID,
        cc.strName AS Exam,
        cc.dblWeighting, 
        sci.dblModeratedComponentScorePercent AS Mark
    FROM 
        tblStudentComponentInformation sci 
    INNER JOIN 
        tblCourseComponents cc ON sci.lngExamID = cc.lngExamID
    WHERE 
        sci.lngRelatedScoreID IN (73652)
)
SELECT 
    [ID], 
    ROUND(SUM(Mark * dblWeighting), 4) AS TotalWeightedMark
FROM 
    RawData
GROUP BY 
    [ID]
```

And here's what I get back:

| ID | TotalWeightedMark |
| --- | --- |
| 73652 | 0.9087 |

My question is why this appears to be truncating rather than rounding, given that I've not specified anything other than the default value for the final parameter of the `ROUND` function.

I wondered if it's because of using `FLOAT` rather than `DECIMAL` for the columns, but in this case there isn't any rounding required in the calculations, except for the one calculation where I've specified to round from 5 digits to 4.

Can anyone advise?

In case it's relevant, I'm using SQL Server 2017.

Thanks.

Comment: If you want precise values, why are you using a floating point value?

Comment: Short answer: don't use float, use decimal

Comment: Note the word "approximate" in the [float documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql).

Comment: @Larnu - how do you get (0.905*0.75)+(0.92*0.25) to equal less than either of the marks?!  And to answer your question, this is a database that I've inherited with these column definitions. As I said in my post, I understand that there can be rounding errors in calculations with FLOAT cols, but there shouldn't be any rounding going on in a simple calculation such as this.

Comment: It's not a SQL or SQL Server behaviour.  It's a mis-understanding of how floats work; floats are not magically infinitely precise, they're base-2 ***approximations*** of base-10 numbers *(the base 10 numbers that you're using **do not exist** in base-2, and so have to be approximated, thus you get rounding 'errors')*.  Search online for explanations of floating point behaviour, then use decimals.

Comment: Essential reading --> [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @AndrewRichards, run this from a command-prompt: `sqlcmd -Q "SELECT CAST(0.905 AS float);"`. The result is `0.90500000000000003`.

Comment: Nothing is "simple" when you're using floating point values. But there is most certainly rounding going on. `0.90875` as a floating point value is actually `0.908749999999999946709294817992486059665679931640625`. For *display* purposes this is rounded up to `0.9875`. This is why your value is rounded **down** when you apply `ROUND`, not up, as it's actual value is (just) less than `0.90875`.

Comment: Whether a calculation is "simple" in base 10 is unfortunately not relevant when we're talking base 2 floating point. The extremely simple value `0.1` is already not exactly representable.

Comment: Okay - thanks - I understand. Will read through that article @Jamiec - thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @Charlieface - thanks - that's helpful, and I'll definitely steal the pizza-cutter analogy when explaining this to other people!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been mentioned in the comments, the "problem" is the data type, not the expression.

If we take the below example:

```sql
SELECT [ID],
       SUM(FloatWeighting*FloatMark) AS Float,
       SUM(Decimalweighting*DecimalMark) AS Decimal,
       CONVERT(decimal(18,12),SUM(FloatWeighting*FloatMark)) AS ConvertedFloat,
       ROUND(SUM(FloatWeighting*FloatMark),4) AS RoundedFloat,
       ROUND(SUM(Decimalweighting*DecimalMark),4) AS RoundedDecimal
FROM (VALUES(73652,'Flight Dynamics and Control Exam      ',CONVERT(float,0.75),CONVERT(decimal(3,2),0.75),CONVERT(float,0.905),CONVERT(decimal(4,3),0.905)),
            (73652,'Flight Dynamics and Control Coursework',CONVERT(float,0.25),CONVERT(decimal(3,2),0.25),CONVERT(float,0.92),CONVERT(decimal(4,3),0.92)))V(ID,Exam,FloatWeighting,DecimalWeighting,FloatMark,DecimalMark)
GROUP BY ID;
```

If you run this, you get the following results:

```sql
ID    Float   Decimal ConvertedFloat RoundedFloat RoundedDecimal
----- ------- ------- -------------- ------------ --------------
73652 0.90875 0.90875 0.908750000000 0.9088       0.90880
```

Notice that the rounded `decimal` value provides the value you expect, but the rounded `float` does not. This is because, as discussed in the comments, the floating point value isn't a base 10 value, but a base 2 value. As a result the `float` value `0.90875` isn't *actually* `0.90875`, it's `0.908749999999999946709294817992486059665679931640625`. Notice that this value is actually (just) less than `0.90875`.

Because of this when you apply the function `ROUND` the value above is used, and when you `ROUND` that value to 4 decimal places then `0.9087` *is* the correct answer.

The real solution here, therefore, is to fix your design and `ALTER` your table to make the columns a `decimal`. As an example, that might be:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.tblCourseComponents ALTER COLUMN Mark decimal(4,3);
```

Note that you would need to use an appropriate scale and precision for your *actual* values.

If you can't change the data type, or at least not right now, then you can explicitly convert the value to a `decimal` first before your arithmetic. For example:

```sql
ROUND(SUM(CONVERT(decimal(3,2),Weighting)*CONVERT(decimal(4,3),Mark)),4)
```

Again, ensure you use appropriate precisions and scales for your data .